# Generate random numbers with different probabilities within given ranges

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, probability

Is there a simple algorithm that will print results of rolling a die such that the probability of getting 1,2,3,4,5 is 1/9 and the probability of getting a 6 is 3/9.

I would like to implement this in Java and intentionally only use Math.random(), if statements, for/ while loops.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dice Sum Probability with Different types of Dice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854866/dice-sum-probability-with-different-types-of-dice)

Comment: Very crudely you could generate a random value in the range 1...9 and return 6 for a value of 7, 8 or 9?  Not really an algorithm as such but it's certainly simple.

Comment: Probability of getting 6 should be 4/9 to make the sum of all events 1, unless you want the probabilities of 1..5 to be 1/8, then p(6) = 3/8

Comment: The correct probability of 6 is P(6) = 4/9 as you suggested for the sum of all events to be 1. Alex Rundenko, did you come up with anything?

Answer (score 1):

As others suggested to make the sum of all events equal to 1, then number 9 will have a probability of 4/9 to be chosen.

Generate a random number between 1 and 9, inclusive on both ends. If the number be 1 to 5, you rolled that number, otherwise, you rolled 6. Note that there are 4 chances in this scheme to roll a 6, and 5 total chances to roll 1 through 5.

```
Random random = new Random();
int roll = random.nextInt(9) + 1; // create a random number

if (roll > 5) {
    System.out.println("You rolled a 6");
}
else {
    System.out.println("You rolled a " + roll);
}
```

To simulate more dice rolls you can add the above logic inside a for loop that runs for as many loops as you want.

Comment: the reasoning is correct. Thanks for the 2 cents

Comment: @CarmelMonga glad to help, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Generating values for random variables with a certain distribution usually works like this:

- You have a function which generates a random `0 <= q < 1`,
- You apply the [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) and you obtain the value of your variable.

In your case you have a discrete random variable. You need an instance of `Random`:

`private static final Random random = new Random();`

the values assumed by the variable:

`private static final double[] values = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0};`

Compute the *cumulative distribution function* (sum of probabilities of the values up to the specific value) for these values:

`private static final double[] cdf = {1.0 / 9, 2.0 / 9, 3.0 / 9, 4.0 / 9, 5.0 / 9, 1.0};`

You random generating function will return the last value for which the cdf is not greater than `q`:

```java
   public static double randomValue() {
      double q = random.nextDouble();
      for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
         if (q > cdf[i]) continue;
         return values[i];
      }
      throw new IllegalStateException();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straightforward:

```
// Pass in an instance of class Random
public static int gen(Random r) { 
  int i = r.nextInt(9); // uniformly generate 0,...,8 inclusive
  if (i < 5) {
    return i + 1;       // returns 1,...,5 w/ probability 1/9
  } else {
    return 6;           // returns 6 w/ probability 4/9
  }
}
```

Warning, I no longer have a Java compiler on my machine, so I haven't compiled this.  However, the algorithm is valid as confirmed in another language.

Comment: The reasoning behind the algorithm is spot on. It should work. Should it not compile, I would tweak it.